# Как можно грамотно прописать CSS для элемент списка?

Tags: css

Есть элемент списка

Главнаястраница

Этот элемент списка имеет нижнее подчёркивание.
Сейчас CSS для него:

```
.nav
{
width: 240px;
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 0px 7px 5px;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #666666;
}
```

[image]

Как грамотно прописать CSS, чтобы элемент выглядел так?

[image]

Лишних тэгов быть не должно, только код

Главнаястраница

Comment: >Лишних тэгов быть не должно, только код `<li>Главная</br>страница</li>`

> [Permitted parent elements An <ul>, <ol> or <menu> element. Though not a non-conforming usage, the obsolete <dir> may also be a parent.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Comment: Простите, топикстартер, у вас </br> а вроде нужно <br />

Comment: eicto, я имел ввиду подчёркивание нельзя другими тегами. Ваш вариант не подходит, так как маркер выходит за область подчёркивания. Нужно. чтобы и маркер был подчёркнут.

Comment: используйте :after http://jsfiddle.net/bAnw2/1/

Comment: А как его использовать, применимо к моей ситуации?

Comment: я не знаю вашу ситуацию, попробуйте тому дракону что лижет пятки Шиве, объяснить, что вы хотите, скажите :after. в конце рассказа.

Comment: Чего? Ситуация в вопросе понятно описана.

Comment: я  не менее понятно описал решение в fiddle

Comment: А, извените. Я просто не обратил внимание на jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте, может скажу глупость, но если добавить свойство display: block;

Comment: У меня в таком случае просто маркер пропал. А он нужен.

Comment: Попробуйте display: list-item;

Comment: display: list-item; тоже не даёт никакого результата.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте text-align: right;